# Impersonating a user on a different domain. ASP.NET

Tags: .net, impersonation

I'm trying to impersonate a user on a different domain (which I'm connected to via VPN) and i'm receiving the following error:
 *`Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.`*

Does anyone have any knowledge of how to go about impersonating a user from a different domain?

The impersonation tag i'm using is:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" userName="myUsername" password="myPassword"/>
```

and the code where it will break and give me the error is as follows:

```
File.OpenRead(pathToMyFile);
```

This code works if i'm on the other domain. So i'm pretty sure I need to create a token and a trust relationship but I have no idea of how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide the code you are using to attempt to achieve this.

Comment: I've added the code in my original post.

Comment: Why don't you just run the worker process as that user?